# Why I cannot set canvas's width via binding method?

Tags: xaml, uwp

My UI elements' layout (nest relation) is:

```
toolbarGrid -> toolbarCanvas -> toolbarPanel -> some buttons
```

My purpose is to make animation of those buttons.
The issue is that I use `Debug.Write()` to monitor the `Width` and `ActualWidth` parameters of the UI elements. And I found that when App screen size is changed, only `toolbarGrid` size is changed accordingly. While the other UI elements' sizes are not changed at all, although I use Binding method to bind their `Width` and `ActualWidth` to `toolbarGrid`.

So how can I set their `Width` and `ActualWidth` so that they could change according to App screen's real size?

```
toolbarPanel width = 1920, actualWidth = 1920
toolbarGrid width = NaN, actualWidth = 1034
toolbarBackground width = 1920, actualWidth = 1920
toolbarCanvas width = 1920, actualWidth = 1920
```

---

```
  <Grid x:Name="gridTotal">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Rectangle x:Name="recTangle1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="recTangle2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="8" Grid.ColumnSpan="12"/>

        <Grid x:Name="toolbarGrid" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="8" Grid.ColumnSpan="12">
            <Canvas x:Name="toolbarCanvas" Width="{Binding ElementName=toolbarGrid, Path=ActualWidth}">
                <RelativePanel x:Name="toolbarPanel" Canvas.Top="0" Width="{Binding ElementName=toolbarGrid, Path=ActualWidth}">
                    <Image x:Name="toolbarBackground" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/MainPage/toolbar/toolbar-background2.png" 
                       Width="{Binding ElementName=toolbarGrid, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                       Height="{Binding ElementName=toolbarGrid, Path=ActualHeight}" Stretch="Fill" />

                    <Viewbox x:Name="vb2" Stretch="Uniform" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" Margin="20,0,20,0"
                         Height="{Binding ElementName=recTangle1, Path=ActualHeight}" 
                         Width="{Binding ElementName=recTangle1, Path=ActualWidth}">
                        <Button x:Name="toolbarHistory" Style="{StaticResource toolbarImageStyle}">
                            <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/MainPage/toolbar/toolbar-history.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                        </Button>
                    </Viewbox>
                </RelativePanel>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand your problem. If the problem was that u like to `Elements` follow actual screen size this one works. I changed the `XAML` code and hoping that next solution works fine for you. I rid of the `Canvas` because that element cause the problem. Anyway, in this example u do not need it (unless u have planned some other use later). And also to set Row/Column Width/Height values is unneeded. Bindings are also unnessessary.

```
<Grid x:Name="gridTotal">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Rectangle x:Name="recTangle1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="recTangle2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="8" Grid.ColumnSpan="12"/>

    <Grid x:Name="toolbarGrid" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="8" Grid.ColumnSpan="12">
        <RelativePanel x:Name="toolbarPanel" Canvas.Top="0">
            <Image x:Name="toolbarBackground" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/MainPage/toolbar/toolbar-background2.png" Stretch="Fill" />
            <Viewbox x:Name="vb2" Stretch="Uniform" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" Margin="20,0,20,0">
                <Button x:Name="toolbarHistory">
                    <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/MainPage/toolbar/toolbar-history.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                </Button>
            </Viewbox>
        </RelativePanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```